# intent for two buttons to two different activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, java1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, java2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

the buttons don't seem to work at all and the app crashes when button is pressed, i have 2 buttons that when clicked go to different activities fro the main activity.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @kakajan they don't seem to be working when i click them they crash

Comment: Did you add your new activities inside your `manifest` file? You must put them inside `<application>` tag like: `<activity android:name=".newActivity"/>`

Comment: yup did that for the classes that have to be shown when the button is pressed but is still doesn't work @Kakajan
<activity android:name=".java1" >
        </activity>

Comment: what error you get when you press the button?

Comment: unfortunately the app has stopped error

Comment: You should be able to check the logcat output for the exception associated with the crash. Copy & paste that exception as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `intent` at `Class Level` and refer it in `onCreate()` ,then just use `startActivity` in `onClick()`

```
Intent intent,i; //Globally

    onCreate(Bundle savedInstances)
    {
     ...
     i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),java2.class);
     intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),java1.class);
     ...
    }
```

Then in onClick

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            yourclassname.this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            yourclassname.this.startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

And make sure your java1 and java2 classes are of type Activity/ListActivity

Comment: i declared the intent before the increase method and in oncreatemethod i put in this 

i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),java2.class);
     intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),java1.class);

Comment: and after the oncreatemethod i put my code given above by you and it still doesn't work @rajan